# Checking last element in string and removing c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a list of strings that I am wanting to remove the `,` from the end of the string. I looked up online how to check to see if you are at the last index of a string and on how to remove the last index from the string. But when I do the following, it still does not seem to remove the `,`.

```
List<string> groceryList = "apple, fruit, banana, carrots, mango";
var x = "buy "; 
var y = groceryList;

foreach (var item in y)
{
    x = x + item + ", ";
    
   if (item == y.Last()){
      x.Remove(x.Length - 1); }
}
```

I even tried `x.Remove(x.Length - 2)` thinking it would hit the `,` but the variable `x` still contains the `,` at the end of the string. Also I tried `x.Remove(x.Last())` but it still does not remove the `,` after `mango`. So it will show `mango,` instead of `mango`.

Comment: In .NET, strings are immutable. If you read the docs for `string.Remove`, you will see that it _returns_ a new string with characters removed. You can't modify a string in C#

Comment: Maybe you should use the if to not add that  `,`  so you don't have to remove it?:

Comment: Can you please tell me whether your code compiles? In particular this line: `List<string> groceryList = "apple, fruit, banana, carrots, mango";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reassign the value of the x. The following code should give you the desired result.

```
x = x.Remove(x.Length - 2, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're better off avoiding the dangling comma in the first place.

Try this:

```
List<string> groceryList = new List<string>() { "apple", "fruit", "banana", "carrots", "mango" };
string x = $"buy {String.Join(", ", groceryList)}";
```

That gives me `buy apple, fruit, banana, carrots, mango`.

---

If you want to build it yourself, then an `for` loop is the way to go:

```
for (int i = 0; i < groceryList.Count; i++)
{
    x += groceryList[i];
    if (i < groceryList.Count - 1)
        x += ", ";
}
```

---

Or an enumerator:

```
var e = groceryList.GetEnumerator();
if (e.MoveNext())
{
    while (true)
    {
        x += e.Current;
        if (e.MoveNext())
            x += ", ";
        else
            break;
    }
}
```